# Is there a C# equivalent of VB6's Choose() function?

Tags: c#

Is there a C# equivalent of VB6's Choose() function?

```
day = Choose(month,31,28,30)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not really. You can of course create an array an use its indexed getter:

```
day = new[] { 31, 28, 30 }[month];
```

Alternatively, you could - I wouldn't - import the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.aspx) namespace and do:

```
day = Interaction.Choose(month, 31, 28, 30);
```

I do not know how much your example is simplified, but in the case that you are actually looking for a way to find the numbers of days in a specific month, try [`DateTime.DaysInMonth()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx):

```
day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(2008, 2);
// day == 29
```

Answer (score 8):

If it is really about the days in a month I would follow the advice others have given. However if you really need a Choose function you can easily build one yourself. For example like this:

```
public static T Choose<T>(int index, params T[] args)
{
    if (index < 1 || index > args.Length)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
    else
    {
        return args[--index];
    }
}

// call it like this
var day = Choose<int?>(1, 30, 28, 29);  // returns 30
```

I did not bother to make the first argument a double, but this can easily be done. It is also possible to make a non-generic version...

Answer (score 4):

I will sugest, you use [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) instead :)

Answer (score 2):

My first guess will be

```
var days = new[] { 31, 28, 30 }[month];
```

Although [native version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/824bz7dy(VS.80).aspx) does all sorts of crazy stuff, like rounding and kind-of-bounds-checking.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: No.

If you are looking to do only what you sample is doing, try DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month)